# How to interpret ffmpeg -pix_fmts output?

Tags: ffmpeg

Running ffmpeg -pix_fmts returns a list of formats.  Snip:

```
IO... yuv444p16be            3            48
..H.. vdpau_mpeg4            0             0
..H.. dxva2_vld              0             0
IO... rgb444le               3            12
IO... rgb444be               3            12
IO... bgr444le               3            12
```

What do the I O and H on the right side mean?  What are the numbers in the 2 leftmost columns?

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [header](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=cmdutils.c;h=78b0094dc03ea596ac705182c102daa514454085;hb=HEAD#l1616) on top:

```
printf("Pixel formats:\n"
       "I.... = Supported Input  format for conversion\n"
       ".O... = Supported Output format for conversion\n"
       "..H.. = Hardware accelerated format\n"
       "...P. = Paletted format\n"
       "....B = Bitstream format\n"
       "FLAGS NAME            NB_COMPONENTS BITS_PER_PIXEL\n"
       "-----\n");
```

So the numbers are "number of components" (typically 3 for RGB or YUV, but can also be 4 for RGBA/YUVA or 1 for palette-based formats, or 0 for hardware-wrappers). The last one is the number of bits per pixel for all color components together.